# Deep learning training with nonidentical images?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am actually reconstructing some images using dual photography. Next, I want to train a network to reconstruct clear images by removing noise (Denoising autoencoder).

The input for training the network is reconstructed images, whereas, the output is ground truth or computer based standard test images. Now the input e.g., Lena is some how not exact version of Lena with image shifted in positions and some artifacts.

If I keep input as my reconstructed image and training output as Lena test image (computer standard test image) , will it work?
I only want to know if input/output shifted or some details missing in one of them (due to some cropping) would work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors like your images for training and the architecture of the network.

However, what you want to do is to make a network that learns the noise or low level information and for this purpose Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN) are very popular. You can read about them [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan). Maybe, after you have tried your approach and if the results are not satisfactory then try using GANs, like, DCGAN (Deep Convolution GAN).

Comment: Thanks for the reply please check my edited post. Giving more details. Would like to stick to DCAN

Comment: What is 'CAN'? Never heard of this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for not training your model with those images. The autoencoder, if well trained, will eventually learn the transformation if there is enough data.

However, if you have the 'positive' images, I strongly recommend you to create your own noisy images and then train in that controlled working area. You will simplify your problem and it will be easier to solve.

What is stopping you from doing just that?

Comment: Thanks, The problem is that I am unable to replicate the ringing effect and noise artifacts on the 'positive computer based test images' similar to the ones I get in reconstructed images from my method. That is why i wanted to ask this question before training my network if it will work as the input and ouput images are slightly misaligned and not the same.

Comment: Could you post more examples of pairs of images? It will work up to some poing if the images are slightly misaligned and you have enough data

Comment: Hey, I think all my images are slightly misaligned, I am using test images (Lena pepper, pirate etc.). It is understood that even if i perfectly size my target image, which is printed on A4 paper and reconstruct it, there will always be some difference compared to ideal test images.

Comment: then try to train the model and chech the results. Think aout preprocessing the data so you can at least do some alignment first